# i keep getting the error number or query values and destination fields are not the same

Tags: database, vb.net

i really need help to see whats wrong

```
Private Sub btnSaveData_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnSaveData.Click
    Try

        conn.Open()
        cmd = conn.CreateCommand
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
        cmd.CommandText = "insert into vbsavedata([Student ID, First Name, Surname, Address, Postcode, Telephone, Grade, Section, Specialization])VALUES('" + tbstudentid.Text + "','" + tbfirstname.Text + "','" + tbsurname.Text + "','" + tbaddress.Text + "','" + tbpostcode.Text + "','" + tbtelephone.Text + "','" + tbgrade.Text + "','" + tbsection.Text + "','" + tbspecialization.Text + "')"
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        MessageBox.Show("Record Saved MS Access", "VB Save Database", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information
                         )
        conn.Close()

    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "VB Save Database", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)

    End Try

End Sub
```

i cant really see whats wrong please help

Comment: Have you tried removing the [ ] 's

Comment: Holy SQL Injection attack, Batman!

Answer (score 0):

FWIW - IF, and it is a big IF, I use text commands instead of SPROCs I've found using XElement helpful, mostly because of embedded expressions.

```
    Dim mycommand As New SqlCommand
    mycommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text
    Dim cmd As XElement
    ' the <v> nodes use embedded expressions
    cmd = <cmd>
              <ins>insert into tbl_cus(name,class,phone) </ins>
              <vals>values (<v>'<%= TextBox1.Text %>',</v>
                  <v>'<%= TextBox2.Text %>',</v>
                  <v>'<%= TextBox3.Text %>'</v>);</vals>
          </cmd>

    mycommand.CommandText = cmd.Value
    '  mycommand.CommandText  
    '      insert into tbl_cus(name,class,phone) values ('TB val one','TB val two','TB val three');
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at just this part of the SQL, and we can see the problem:

```
into vbsavedata([Student ID, First Name,
```

The opening square-bracket (`[`) is never closed, and never even attempted for the other multi-word column names.

Worse, this code is **crazy-vulnerable** to SQL injection issues. It is **NEVER** okay to use string concatenation to build user values into an SQL statement! You should spend a few minutes reading up on how to do parameterized queries for MS Access.

Finally, there is one more concern with the use of the `conn` Connection. It's usually a *bad idea* to try to re-use the same connection object throughout the application. This actually makes things *SLOWER*, because it interferes with the existing connection pooling abilities in ADO.Net. Worse, if there is an exception running the query, the `.Close()` call would be skipped. Instead, common practice is to create a new connection for nearly every query as part of a `Using` block, which will ensure the connection is closed properly *even in the case of an exception*.

In other words, you need something more like this:

```
Private Sub btnSaveData_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnSaveData.Click
    Dim SQL As String = "INSERT INTO vbsavedata([Student ID], [First Name], Surname, Address, Postcode, Telephone, Grade, Section, Specialization]) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)"

    Try
        Dim conn As New OleDbConnection("connection string here")
        Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand(SQL, conn)

        ' Match up with the actual column types and lengths from the database
        cmd.Parameters.Add("Student ID", OleDbType.VarChar, 8).Value = tbstudentid.Text
        cmd.Parameters.Add("First Name", OleDbType.VarWChar, 15).Value = tbfirstname.Text
        cmd.Parameters.Add("Surname", OleDbType.VarWChar, 20).Value = tbsurname.Text
        cmd.Parameters.Add("Address", OleDbType.VarWChar, 60).Value = tbaddress.Text
        cmd.Parameters.Add("PostCode", OleDbType.VarChar, 10).Value = tbpostcode.Text
        cmd.Parameters.Add("Telephone", OleDbtype.VarChar, 14).Value = tbtelephone.Text
        cmd.Parameters.Add("Grade", OleDbType.VarChar, 3).Value = tbgrade.Text
        cmd.Parameters.Add("Section", OleDbType.VarChar, 12).Value = tbsection.Text
        cmd.Parameters.Add("Specialization", OleDbType.VarWChar, 40).Value = tbspecialization.Text

        conn.Open()
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        MessageBox.Show("Record Saved MS Access", "VB Save Database", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information

    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "VB Save Database", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
    Finally  ' Using blocks are more common, but in the case where you already have a Try/Catch closing the in Finally block is also okay
        conn.Dispose()
    End Try

End Sub
```